# Dynamic chained drop downs on page refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have the following scenario. I have 2 drop downs. The options in the first one are loaded on document.ready. The options for the second one are loaded when the user makes a selection in the first drop down. I'm using jQuery to populate both and everything works peachy.

These drop downs live inside a form that is submitted via a GET and the same page is returned as the ActionResult. So here's my problem, once the form is submitted, I need the drop downs to maintain their values as well as populate the appropriate option lists.

My idea so far has been to parse out the query parameters and set the values that way. I'm not sure how to repopulate the second drop down list though.

**NOTE** this is a simplified example and I actually have a whole bunch of drop downs that are chained several levels deep so I need a somewhat generic solution.

Comment: @yadas ,  store the last selected value in a global variable and set the second dropdown also while the page is loading second time??but i think there is a way to preserver the previous selected values on page load...again

Answer (score 0):

When I have done this, each time you call an action, you need to rebuild the list of values in the model.  Then, your model also stores the selected value, which is automatically retained.

Here's an example of an address control where I have a state drop down.

First, my model

```
public class AddressModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
    [DisplayName("Address Line 1")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Address Line 2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
    [DisplayName("City")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
    [DisplayName("State")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Zip code is required")]
    [DisplayName("Zip Code")]
    [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be five digits.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d{5}", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be five digits.")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> States { get; set; }

    public SelectList StatesSelectList
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(States, "Value", "Key");
        }
    }
}
```

And here are my actions, all but the important parts omitted

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    var model = new AddressModel()
    {
        States = GetStateList();
    };

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(AddressModel model)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //do stuff here
    }

    model.States = GetStateList();

    return View(model);
}
```

And here's how it looks in my view

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(x => x.State)%>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.State, Model.StatesSelectList)%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.State)%>
```

Because the property `AddressModel.State` is bound to a control, its value is retained each time the post action is called.

Comment: How would you handle a situation where you had a list of countries and the user could select the countries and depending on that selection the states was populated dynamically?

Comment: I would use jquery's ajax function to pull back json from the server and rebuild the second dropdown with the results.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  Then on the action I would have to use the selected country to build the model data for the states.  the selected values would be retained for both.